# Make Ajax call for all items in array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, parse-platform

I want to make an Ajax call for every item in an array, and when all the calls have returned, I want to call another function.

To make things a little more complicated, I'm using [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/) to make the Ajax call.

This is my code:

```
getCsvData: function(url) {
    var _this = thisl
    Papa.parse(url, {
        download: true,
        complete: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
},

getBackendData: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var results = {};
    _this.numeratorIds.forEach(function(d) {
        var url = _this.constructUrl(d.id, d.query_type);
        results[url] = _this.getCsvData(url);
    });
   // When everything is finished... 
   // call another function to render the data.
},
```

I'm not sure this is quite right - is there a better way of doing things?

NB: I realise it's slower to do multiple Ajax calls than to chain URL parameters and make a single call, but I think it's the right thing to do in my situation - I am working with a very large, very static database, and it will mean that I can cache these queries more often.

Comment: I don't get what your question is. How to call the other function once your Ajax calls are complete?

Comment: @user3779812 yes exactly. Sorry, I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to do make multiple AJAX calls instead doing of that the controller return List of object that you want. Then you will not need to make multiple Ajax calls. What you will need is just one Ajax and you will have list of objects that you want and then you can bind that data onto your views.

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Thanks, however I'd really prefer to make multiple calls, as per the explanation at the bottom of the question.